# Query to pad left of a field with 0's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been working on a query (in sql Server TSQL) which fills left of a number with 0's so output is always 5 digit.

So:

```
Select MuNumber From Mytable
```

for data 11,011,2132,1111

```
Creates output like 
00011
02134
01111
```

I tried Lpad Function but numer of 0's can be different.

if Munumber is 1 we need 0000 and If MyNumber is 34 we need 000

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that MuNumber is VARCHAR simply use `RIGHT`

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + MuNumber, 5)
FROM Mytable
```

Otherwise you need to convert it first

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MuNumber), 5)
FROM Mytable
```

And in general you can use this pattern:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 10;

SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @num) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), MuNumber), @num)
FROM Mytable
```

Comment: Very nice! I totally forgot about right function is TSQ, Let me test it.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers both +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select right('00000'+cast(col as varchar(5)),5) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the user defined function udfLeftSQLPadding where you can find the source codes at [SQL Pad Leading Zeros](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx)

After you create the function on your database, you can use it as follows

```
select 
    dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding(MuNumber,5,'0')
from dbo.Mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
declare @n int = 6

select stuff(replicate('0', @n), 6-len(n), len(n), n)
from (values('123'), ('2493'), ('35')) as x(n)
```